# Dexron III or Dexron III synthetic ATF

Tags: atf

Should I continue to use Dexron III or the Dexron III synthetic ATF oil for my 1964 Buick Riviera?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will find either of these options available.  Manufacturers are no longer able to produce ATF and call it "Dexron III".  GM has replaced that fluid with Dexron VI which is fully compatible.

Whether it's fully synthetic or not doesn't make much difference.  They both have the same specifications.

Comment: DEXRON VI should either be fully synthetic or blend. If it's full, it'd say it on the bottle. I don't think a conventional base oil would be good enough to meet GM's standards. But yes, DEX VI will replace DEX III and should be used because it is a much better alternative, even for an older vehicle.